# Validating select element based on pattern with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm developing an Angular app and I have a form set up which  I need to run validation on. One of the form elements is a `<select>`, like this:

```
<select name="noOfPeople" ng-model="noOfPeople">
    <option>No of people*</option>
    <option ng-repeat="amt in [] | range:12">{{ amt +1 }}</option>
</select>
```

Because the design doesn't allow for labels on form elements, the label is essentially the first option in the select element. I want this control to be invalid unless it matches the following pattern: `/^[0-9]$/`.

I have tried using `ng-pattern` on the `<select>` however that doesn't seem to have any effect, Angular always thinks the control is valid.

The only other way I can think of doing it is writing a function in my controller to check if this control is valid and block the form from submitting if it's not. But I don't want to introduce a random validation function into my nice clean controller.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: What about `ng-submit` ?

Comment: Using ng-submit on the form and running the validation against a $scope function.

Comment: I'd like to keep validation functions out of my controllers if possible, it doesn't seem like they belong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ng-options` attribute here, rather than `ng-repeat`, and attribute a blank value to any options you wish to ignore. For example:

```
<select name="noOfPeople" ng-model="noOfPeople" ng-options="value for value in [] | range:12">
    <option value="">No of people*</option>
    <option value="">This won't count either!</option>
</select>
<p>Selected Value: {{noOfPeople}}<p>
```

If you explicitly require the regex checking to occur, you could write a filter and add it to the ng-options.